# the method equals(object) in the type object is not applicable to the arguments

Tags: java, class, object, methods, equals

I have a program where I must see if the two names entered are equal and get other information about the names(such as length, or get the initials). Everything else runs properly but the equals method.

I get the error:
the method equals(object) in the type object is not applicable to the arguments(Name, Name)

and I cannot figure out how to resolve this error. Can someone please help me understand what the error means?

Here is my class name with all the methods:

```
class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String first, String middle, String last) {
        firstName = first;
        middleName = middle;
        lastName = last;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddle() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String firstMiddleLast() {
        return (firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }

    public String lastFirstMiddle() {
        return (lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object name, Object otherName) {
        (name.toString()).toUpperCase();
        (otherName.toString()).toUpperCase();
        if (name.equals(otherName))
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }

    public String initials() {
        String initials = (firstName.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) + middleName.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) + lastName.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1));
        return initials;
    }

    public int length() {
        String wholeName = (firstName + middleName + lastName);
        return wholeName.length();
    }

}
```

Here is the other class that tests name.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String first, middle, last;
        String firstOne, middleOne, lastOne;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Name Program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name of the first person...");
        System.out.println("Enter the first name: ");
        first = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the middle name: ");
        middle = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the last name: ");
        last = input.nextLine();


        Name name = new Name(first, middle, last);

        System.out.println("Name of the second person...");
        System.out.println("Enter the first name: ");
        firstOne = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the middle name: ");
        middleOne = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the last name: ");
        lastOne = input.nextLine();

        Name otherName = new Name(firstOne, middleOne, lastOne);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Information about the first person: ");
        System.out.println("Full Name: " + name.firstMiddleLast());
        System.out.println("Last name first: " + name.lastFirstMiddle());
        System.out.println("Initials: " + name.initials());
        System.out.println("Name length: " + name.length());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Information about the second person: ");
        System.out.println("Full Name: " + otherName.firstMiddleLast());
        System.out.println("Last name first: " + otherName.lastFirstMiddle());
        System.out.println("Initials: " + otherName.initials());
        System.out.println("Name length: " + otherName.length());

        if (equals(name, otherName))
            System.out.println("They are the same");
        else
            System.out.println("They are not the same");
    }
}
```

Comment: `name.equals(otherName)`

Comment: @Azar I fixed that, but when I enter in the same name again for otherName, it still tells me that it is not equal

Comment: I wrote a more detailed answer for you.

Comment: Do realize `(name.toString()).toUpperCase();`, and `(otherName.toString()).toUpperCase();` does nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this method needs to be fixed:

```
public boolean equals(Object name) 
{ //Now it is an override, so we use Object
    return firstMiddleLast().toUpperCase().equals(((Name)name).firstMiddleLast().toUpperCase());
}
```

Your version uses `(name.toString()).toUpperCase();` which is meaningless for two reasons. The first is that it creates a new `String` object (because strings are immutable) twice, giving the statement zero effect. Second, you're calling `toString()` on a class for which you have not overridden that method, so you're going to get a garbled bunch of numbers and letters.

Finally, you need to change this:

```
if (equals(name, otherName))
        System.out.println("They are the same");
else
        System.out.println("They are not the same");
```

to this:

```
if (name.equals(otherName))
        System.out.println("They are the same");
else
        System.out.println("They are not the same");
```

Since the `equals()` method is defined in in `Name`, we need to use it on a `Name` object. Since you did not try to use it on a name object, it tried to call the one parameter `equals()` method defined by `Object` in `TestName`, hence your error.

Comment: Thank you! i didnt know that would be a problem.I changed based on your suggestions, but even when I enter the same name twice it still says the names aren't the same.

Comment: @user3904967 Whoops sorry about that, should work now. I see that you're new to StackOverflow. If this answers your question, I would appreciate you clicking the checkmark next to it to mark it as "accepted."